# How to remove the last character of a string in Golang?

Tags: string, go

I want to remove the very last character of a string, but before I do so I want to check if the last character is a "+". How can this be done?

Comment: Builtin function is available now.
http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSuffix

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here are several ways to remove trailing plus sign(s).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func TrimSuffix(s, suffix string) string {
    if strings.HasSuffix(s, suffix) {
        s = s[:len(s)-len(suffix)]
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := "a string ++"
    fmt.Println("s: ", s)

    // Trim one trailing '+'.
    s1 := s
    if last := len(s1) - 1; last >= 0 && s1[last] == '+' {
        s1 = s1[:last]
    }
    fmt.Println("s1:", s1)

    // Trim all trailing '+'.
    s2 := s
    s2 = strings.TrimRight(s2, "+")
    fmt.Println("s2:", s2)

    // Trim suffix "+".
    s3 := s
    s3 = TrimSuffix(s3, "+")
    fmt.Println("s3:", s3)
}
```

Output:

```
s:  a string ++
s1: a string +
s2: a string 
s3: a string +
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, Go 1.1+ provides `strings.TrimSuffix`.

Answer (score 43):

Based on the comment of @KarthikGR the following example was added:

https://play.golang.org/p/ekDeT02ZXoq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimSuffix("Foo++", "+"))
}
```

returns:

```
Foo+
```

Answer (score 22):

No builtin way. But it's trivial to do manually.

```
s := "mystring+"
sz := len(s)

if sz > 0 && s[sz-1] == '+' {
    s = s[:sz-1]
}
```

Comment: Won't work with unicode, ex "mystringƂ" https://play.golang.org/p/F0j19ceGo75
I know the original question asks for removing the "+", but I came here googling the general answer

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    s := "venga|ese|sabor|"

    newString := ""
    if len(s) > 0 {
        newString = s[:len(s)-1]
    }

    fmt.Println(newString)
}
```

output: **venga|ese|sabor**

go playground:
https://go.dev/play/p/o9ExIEuU0SF

Answer (score -1):

@llazzaro

A simple UTF compliant string trimmer is

```
string([]rune(foo)[:len(foo)-1]))
```

So I'd go with

```
f2 := []rune(foo)
for f2[len(f2)-1] == '+'{
    f2 = f2[:len(f2)-1]
}
foo = string(f2)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/anOwXlfQWaF

I'm not sure why the other answers trimmed the way that they do, because they're trimming bytes.

Comment: Good to point out that it may be important to handle UTF-8. However, your first example is buggy since byte length may not be the same as rune length. Also, the question only wants to know whether the string ends in '+', not remove all trailing '+'.

Comment: @mpx My comment was in reply to llazzaro, but I couldn't respond directly because not enough points
"However, your first example is buggy since byte length may not be the same as rune length" - this is why I use runes in my example; a rune is 1-3 bytes, all the answers use bytes except mine, which is Ok if the final character being removed is a single byte.

"Also, the question only wants to know whether the string ends in '+', not remove all trailing '+'" = all the answers assume that the '+' is being removed.

Comment: I understand the reason for the rune conversion, but there is still a bug. Try the following:  `foo := "\u2211\U0001f642+"; fmt.Printf("%q\n", string([]rune(foo)[:len(foo)-1]))`   You will find extra NULLs on the end rather than truncation.. The example takes the byte length of the string, subtracts 1, then uses it to slice the runes hence it increases the size overall. Depending on the length of the string, it might also panic. Afaik, you should be able to edit your answer here?

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to be talking about the mechanics of slices as a bug; as you may already know a reslice is only ever changing the way the contents of the backing array are 'viewed'; the data in the backing array itself won't be changed by the -1. Only an `append` or `copy` of the data into a new backing array would work there.

Comment: No, slice mechanics work fine as intended, the code offered does not. If someone tries to use the _simple UTF compliant string trimmer_ provided it will fail when there are 1+ codepoints > 127 encoded in the string. This will result in either: No truncation, NULLs appended, or panic. It is buggy and should not be used. Please try the example string I provided above - it makes this very clear. Separately, the second example provided is closer to working, but it is also buggy and will fail on a string that only contains '+' or the empty string (index out of range).

Comment: No, sorry, if you have a better solution then write up an answer.

Comment: 030 and Karthik provided the best answer above (`strings.TrimSuffix`), it also works correctly with Unicode/UTF-8.