# How to access a map entry with a string key stored in a variable in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go

So I have a Go variable `table map[string]string` with some entries. I can access the map values using string keys as expected:

```
table["key"] // ok
```

But when I try to access the map with a string key retrieved from `os.Stdin`...

```
reader, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
key, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') // type "key" (no quotations), press enter
value, _ := table[key] // no value :(
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your key don't include the delimiter '`\n`' included by [`bytes.ReadString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.ReadString):

(and more generally, don't ignore the return values, especially the errors)

See this runnable(!) example on http://ideone.com/qgvsmF:

```
package main

import "bufio"
import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    table := make(map[string]string)

    table["key1"] = "val1"
    table["key2"] = "val2"
    table["key3"] = "val3"

    fmt.Println("Enter a key (followed by Return):")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    val, ok := table[input]
    fmt.Println("val for key '" + input + "' = '" + val + "'(" + fmt.Sprintf("%v", ok) + ")")
}
```

It will show a key equals to:

```
'key2
'
```

[Remove the last character of your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689425/removed-last-character-of-a-string), as in this [runnable example](http://ideone.com/qgvsmF):

```
input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n")
```

Output:

```
Enter a key (followed by Return):
val for key 'key2' = 'val2'(true)
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I just needed to `strings.Trim` the input. Thanks!

Comment: @marcioAlmada trim, or `input[:len(input)-1]`, as I have edited the answer. http://ideone.com/qgvsmF does illustrate it.

Comment: Not sure if the `'\n'` is compatible with all platforms, BTW. Maybe on windows you need to use `'\r'`?

Comment: @marcioAlmada true, I have replaced it with `input = strings.Trim(input, "\r\n")`

Answer (score 3):

The documentation about ReadString says:

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.

So the key variable contains the key string plus \n (or \r\n on Windows), and it cannot be found in the map.